# Requesting clarification regarding type cast

Tags: c, casting

EDIT : Okay , I think that I now get it :

Case 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define function(_a) ((_a)*2)

int main () {
    int (*func)(int) = function(0); // function(0) = 0
    func(7);
...
}
```

syntax is okay , however , during run-time , main will try to access the address NULL , which will result in a software crash in windows / segmentation error in a unix environment.

Case 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define function(_a) ((_a)*2)

int main () {
    int (*func)(int) = function;
    func(7);
...
}
```

compilation error , since "function" is in fact a macro , and not an actual function , therefor, a pointer to function cannot point to it , so to speak.

Case 3 (correct code ):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int function(int _a){return ((_a)*2);};

    int main () {
        int (*func)(int) = function;
        func(7);
    ...

}
```

Have I gotten it right this time ?

Comment: It's a function pointer that's initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: okay , but what happens when calling the function , e.g , `func(7)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int (*func)(int) = 0;` means `func` is a **function pointer** i.e. `pointer to a function` and hence `(*func)` returning an `integer` i.e. first `int` in the statement and which takes an `integer` as an argument i.e. `(int)`. Assigning `int (*func)(int)` to `0` means that the **function pointer** is assigned to point to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , please see my comments on the first answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This line is not what you think it is.

```
 int (*func)(int) = 0;
```

It is a variable (called func) to a pointer to a function that has the signature `int somename(int)` and you are setting it to 0.

For a better understanding consider this:

```
int myfunction(int a) { return 5;}
```

Then this would work

```
 int (*func)(int) = myfunction;
```

Comment: Also worth noting that after that last line of code, the function can be called using `func(10);`

Comment: I see ! , I was completely mistaken ! , actually , the original code was :
`int (*func)(int) = function (0);`
and function was defined thusly :
`#define function(_a) ((_a)*2)`

Comment: but still it doesn't make sense , because `function(0)` returns NULL !

Comment: `function(0)` is equivalent to `0 * 2` which is `0`. Isn't this your expected answer? For example, if `int (*func)(int) = function` where function is defined as `int function(int num) { return num * 2;}` and if you perform `(*func)(10)` you should be getting `20`

Comment: @user1965208 - You cannot use `#define` to create the pointer in this case.

Comment: @Ganesh that's exactly what I thought , this means that the code above contains a compilation error , right ?

EdHeal, please see the edit

Comment: @user1965208 - Please go to http://cfiddle.net/qaUbBK to see how the code should look